# How do I refresh the server in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reload

I have an application where I am sending a JSON file to the server. The JSON file can change so I want it to reload the server everytime it changes. But when I put location.reload() it gives me an error that location is not defined.
***What Should I use instead of location.reload()***

Comment: A server cannot by itself change a browser display.  They are separate computers and not normally connected.  You can either have your browser web page regularly refresh itself with `location.reload()` in the web page itself (not on your server) or by sending an ajax call to the web server periodically asking the server if there is new content.  Or, you can make a continuous webSocket connection to the server and then the server can send you new content whenever it arrives and then your browser Javascript can then display that new content.

Comment: Your server itself will need to monitor the JSON file and update its state whenever it changes.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that I have done before is to use `nodemon` (instead of node) to run your node application.  Nodemon is designed to restart the node application when it detects changes in the file system.  So if you have a node application that writes a JSON file to disk, in the same folder as the node application, then it will restart when the file is changed.

Comment: I use that as well but what I am trying to achieve is every few hours to refresh my browser on localhost without me doing anything. So write it in the code. Just like how you can run location.reload in your normal javascript page and it reloads the browser,

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like "forever".

```
npm install forever
```

Then change the package json

```
"start": "forever start index.js"
```

then whenever you want to force the restart, you just call

```
process.exit(1);
```

this will try to force a restart on your server

Comment: But is there a way without installing anything to refresh the json api website in a function

Comment: Another solution would be to force a breaking error on the server... something like an unhandled Promise rejection.
This is also asuming you have your devops properly setup to restart when it becomes unhealthy.
Not ideal solution anyway, but skips the installing part.

Comment: Why restart the server just to update some state from a JSON file?  Much better to just program the server to monitor the JSON file and update it's internal state when that file changes.